# How to expect an "uninitialized constant" in RSpec test

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to document what happens if someone tries to access a constant within a module that does not exist. For example, consider this module:

```
module Enum
  GOOD = "good"
  BAD = "bad"
end
```

Accessing Enum::GOOD is fine, but Enum::MAYBE will throw a NameError. The only way I've found to show this in a test is by rescuing the error, though what I'd really like is to expect it:

```
describe Enum do
  it "finds valid values" do
    expect(Enum::GOOD).to eq("good")
    expect(Enum::BAD).to eq("bad")
  end

  context "bad values throw NameError" do

    it "allows me to test using rescue" do
      begin
        Enum::NOT_VALID
        fail "should have raised error"
      rescue NameError
      end
    end

    it "does not allow me to expect a raised error" do
      expect(Enum::NOT_VALID).to raise_error(NameError)
    end
  end

end
```

Is using the rescue clause my only/best option here? Keep in mind, I'm not really trying to implement an enum, but trying to document what happens when you try to access a constant in a module which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`raise_error`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#expecting-errors), you should use a block:

```
it "does not allow me to expect a raised error" do
  expect { Enum::NOT_VALID }.to raise_error(NameError)
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was missing! Thanks!